# Task 'installRelease' not found in root project 'VotePlus'. Some candidates are: 'uninstallRelease'

Tags: android, redux, react-native

i Just cloned a react native project and changed the name according to my project name , But it works in debug apk but doesn't works on Release apk got error below screenshot . Does anybody have an idea on solving this and release apk .

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O20Mq.png

Answer (score 3):

We don't have `installRelease`. you can bundle the release with Gradle's assembleRelease command

```
 cd android
./gradlew assembleRelease
```